# Do I need one or more commas in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, commas

> May I suggest that you keep on searching Asda or better yet go back to Primark.

It looks as if at least one comma is needed here. I was thinking:

> May I suggest that you keep on searching Asda or, better yet, go back to Primark.

Are commas necessary?

Comment: If you choose two commas, the first one works better before the or.

Comment: Why not reduce the sentence to its essentials? "**Do this or do that**". You can add a comma before **or** if you like - that's just a stylistic choice. Whether you do or not, you should still normally enclose a "parenthetical clause" such as **better yet** within commas when you drop it into a sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is 'need', in the sense it would be ungrammatical or incorrect without, then I must say 'No.'  The sentence can be okay just the way it is, though only because commas are not necessary where the meaning of the sentence is unambiguous.

However, as the sentence is long and involved, I would definitely suggest parenthetical commas:

> May I suggest that you keep on searching Asda or, better yet, go back to Primark.

Mainly because after all, '*better yet*' is parenthetical in nature.

Comment: Isn't '*after all*' also parenthetical?

Comment: @Jim Sure it is. My original word was 'afterall', which this grammar checker won't pass and had to break into the phrase 'after all'; a one-word parenthetical can go fine without commas.

Comment: @Kris: I agree your first sentence completely. Just because we *often* put commas round parenthetical clauses doesn't mean we *must*. We can also (again optionally) put a comma after "Asda", but the sentence becomes decidedly "top-heavy" if we add all three.

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of the unnecessary "May I" fixes how the sentence reads without additional commas. Of course you may. You are making a suggestion anyway. The over-politeness just makes the sentence heavier.

Comment: I agree, Chris, but I need the sentence to remain as it is, apart from the punctuation. Would the sentence need commas as it is?

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question about commas as posed.

Comment: If the structure can't be changed even a little, then how about "May I suggest that you keep on searching Asda or better yet, go back to Primark."